Is there a way to not start at index.js using Expo Router?
My application is running on Expo using Expo Router. I have an app folder containing a (tabs) folder which has a few pages I am using for the tab bar, including a home.jsx page. The app folder also has an index.jsx file and a _layout.jsx. When the application opens, I want the user to be at app/(tabs)/home.jsx, but I've read that you automatically start at index.jsx first, so I put redirect there to app/(tabs)/home.jsx. While this works, it briefly shows an animation swapping from the index.jsx page to home. Is there a way to only load the app once it is on the home page? I don't like having this animation for the user.
Here's what I've tried:
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "expo-router";

const StartPage = () => {
  return <Redirect href="/home" />;
};

export default StartPage;


Thanks in advance.

The correct approach would be to just rename home.jsx to index.jsx

Ah ok, but my home.jsx file is within the (tabs) folder, which is within the app folder. The index.jsx file is not in the (tabs) folder. Would this be a problem? Or could I go ahead and remove the index.jsx file from app?
home directory: app/(tabs)/home.jsx
index directory: app/index.jsx
Thank you so much!

I have a few questions:
Do you have an (app)/ folder as well?
If not, I'd guess there's a _layout.tsx under app/?
In that case, you don't need an index.jsx there, expo-router should take care of that.
Again, I would suggest just renaming the home.jsx to index.jsx because technically "home" is the "index" or the main page that you want to land on when you start the app.
Lastly, I recommend checking out this repo for a better overview of what the app/ directory should look like.
